# Why does this coroutine block UI Thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

#### Deprecation alert

This code uses the old Coroutines Api. If you're using kotlinx-coroutines 1.1.0 or newer, **this code won't be useful to you**

*The original question was:*

I'm finding that this particular code in my Android App blocks the UI Thread:

```
runBlocking {
    async(CommonPool) {
        Thread.sleep(5000)     
    }.await()
}

textView.text = "Finish!"
```

I've been using coroutines for several tasks, and they never block UI Thread, as can be read in [the documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines.html):

> . Coroutines provide a way to avoid blocking a thread and replace it with a cheaper and more controllable operation: suspension of a coroutine

But curiously, this code:

```
runBlocking {
    async(CommonPool) {
        launch(CommonPool) {
            Thread.sleep(5000)

            runOnUiThread { textView.text = "Finish!" }
        }
    }.await()
}
```

behaves as expected; does not block, waits five seconds then prints the result (I need to update the UI after, and only after the `sleep` is completed)

The documentation says that `async` and `launch` can be used independently and don't need to be combined. In fact, `async(CommonPool)` should be enough.

So what's really going on here? why does it work only with `async+launch` ?

### Update (2021)

[Deprecation alert] This code uses the old Coroutines Api. If you're using kotlinx-coroutines 1.1.0 or newer, forget about this code

My full sample code:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        button1.setOnClickListener {
            runBlocking {
                async(CommonPool) {
                    Thread.sleep(5000L)
                }.await()
            }

            textView1.text = "Finally! I've been blocked for 5s :-("
        }

        button2.setOnClickListener {
            runBlocking {
                async(CommonPool) {
                    launch(CommonPool) {
                        Thread.sleep(5000L)

                        runOnUiThread { textView1.text = "Done! UI was not blocked :-)" }
                    }
                }.await()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

**Note**: this post dates back to the pre-release version of coroutines. I updated the names of dispatchers to match the release version.

`runBlocking` is not the way to start a coroutine on the UI thread because, as its name says, it will block the hosting thread until the coroutine is done. You have to `launch` it in the `Main` context and then switch to the `Default` context for the heavyweight operation. You should also drop the `async-await` pair and use `withContext`:

```
button1.setOnClickListener {
    launch(Main) {
        withContext(Default) {
            Thread.sleep(5000L)
        }
        textView1.text = "Done! UI was not blocked :-)"
    }
}
```

`withContext` will suspend the coroutine until done and then resume it in the parent context, which is `Main`.

Answer (score 1):

As [documentation](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.experimental/run-blocking.html) tells us:

> [`runBlocking`] runs new coroutine and **blocks current thread** interruptibly until its completion. This function should not be used from coroutine. It is designed to **bridge regular blocking code to libraries that are written in suspending style**, to be used in `main` functions and in **tests**.

As quoted, it’s often used in tests that work with regular coroutines and also in `main` methods to wait for the completion of coroutines.

Also, this [tutorial](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/coroutines-guide.md#bridging-blocking-and-non-blocking-worlds) will help understanding its use cases.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry for this late answer, but I hope you find it helpful.

1- Because in the first situation

```
runBlocking {
    async(CommonPool) {
        Thread.sleep(5000L)
    }.await()
}
```

the `runBlocking{}` block will block the main thread until the code inside it finishes, then when we go inside the `runBlocking{}` block we find that you awaited on the `async{}` block, so we must wait until what's inside `async{}` finishes so we must wait for the 5 seconds. That why this code blocks the main thread.

2- But in the second situation:-

```
runBlocking {
    async(CommonPool) {
        launch(CommonPool) {
            Thread.sleep(5000)
            runOnUiThread { textView.text = "Finish!" }
        }
    }.await()
}
```

You didn't await on the `launch{}` block (via using `.join()`), so you the only thing you did inside the `async{}` block is launching the coroutine without waiting for it to finish. It is like that the `async{}` block is empty, so the `async{}.await()` and `runBlocking{}` will not wait for anything to finish. That's why this second situation doesn't block the main thread.
I hope this answers it.