# How to understand and improve async-await in coroutines?

Tags: android, kotlin, async-await, kotlin-coroutines

I would like to improve my `async-await` in coroutines.
This is my solution

```
val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
        get() = job + Dispatchers.IO
[...]
            lifecycleScope.launch(coroutineContext) {
                async {
                    client = viewModel.getClientItem(clientId)
                }.await()
                if (inEditMode != null) {
                    changedEditMode = true
                }
[...]
```

@Marko Topolnik wrote in [Why does this coroutine block UI Thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48663423/why-does-this-coroutine-block-ui-thread)

```
Note: this post dates back to the pre-release version of coroutines. I updated the names of dispatchers to match the release version.

runBlocking is not the way to start a coroutine on the UI thread because, as its name says, it will block the hosting thread until the coroutine is done. You have to launch it in the Main context and then switch to the Default context for the heavyweight operation. You should also drop the async-await pair and use withContext:

button1.setOnClickListener {
    launch(Main) {
        withContext(Default) {
            Thread.sleep(5000L)
        }
        textView1.text = "Done! UI was not blocked :-)"
    }
}
withContext will suspend the coroutine until done and then resume it in the parent context, which is Main.
```

Why doing it with Main Dispatchers and then withContext using Default dispatchers is betters solution than async. It will also block main thread and work the same what is the difference. And how to handle this approaches?

Greetings

EDIT:
My other solution is this below or `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)`

```
            lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
                withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
                    client = viewModel.getItem(clientId)
                }
[...]
}
```

Now as I read I do not use runBlocking and don't block main thread?
In that configuration it works the same as with async-await.
In your opinin that's better solution
?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why doing it with Main Dispatchers and then withContext using Default dispatchers is betters solution than async. It will also block main thread and work the same what is the difference

`withContext` doesn't block, it suspends. The terminology might should similar but the behaviour is very different. While `Thread.sleep` is executing on the `Default` dispatcher (and thus on one of this dispatcher's threads), the main thread can keep running other code. The coroutine launched via `launch(Main)` here is in a suspended state, which means the main dispatcher knows it can execute other things instead. The linked answer here explains why `runBlocking` was a bad idea, because no matter what you launch in it `runBlocking` has to block the current thread while it's executing coroutines inside.

Now back to your code. Note that `async { doStuff() }.await()` makes little sense. It is equivalent to simply `doStuff()`.

Another thing is that you're passing a `job` explicitly to `launch` via the context here. This doesn't seem right, and could lead to problems. If you want to use `Dispatchers.IO`, you don't need to pass a `job` too.

That said, even `Dispatchers.IO` seems like a stretch here. You should instead make `viewModel.getClientItem` a suspend function (if not already), and leave the responsibility of using the right dispatcher to this function. Maybe you don't even need IO at all here, or maybe it's an HTTP or DB call that already has its own thread pool anyway.

So I would replace your whole code with:

```kotlin
lifecycleScope.launch {
    client = viewModel.getClientItem(clientId)
    if (inEditMode != null) {
        hangedEditMode = true
    }
}
```

Comment: It is suspended and it download one data from Room DB

Comment: I can't use Dispatchers.IO it seems the logic is not correct with 100%, because any updates should be in this coroutine context then I could only withContext change to Main if UI change appears and everything will be good. But... could you check edit post plz

Comment: As well I think job is alright here, but I have to remember to destroy it, cancel it on onDestroy what you mean it could provide some problems?

Comment: *I can't use Dispatchers.IO* - but you *are* using it, because you're passing `coroutineContext` to your launch, which has `Dispatchers.IO` in it

Comment: If this talks to a room DB, it's likely main-safe already, and using its own thread pool for dispatch, so you shouldn't even try to customize the dispatcher here I think

Comment: As for the job thing, jobs are the way structured concurrency is wired. If you mess up the job hierarchy, you're escaping structured concurrency and may face issues with cancellation management, exception bubbling etc. You should not need to create a `coroutineContext` at all, nor manage a job manually like this. Instead, you should use `CoroutineScope` for that (if you need to), but here you already have one, `lifecycleScope`, so I don't understand why you're defining a custom context with a job

Comment: Suspend functions by convention internally specify the dispatcher they should be used with, so you **never** have to specify a dispatcher to call a suspend function unless you’re working with code written by someone that ignores this convention. Room, Retrofit, Firebase, Google Play Billing, etc., they all follow this convention.

Comment: So literally these above libraries are comptatible with coroutines and it uses own background dispatcher, but it is not like coroutinContext as I have created and it is not like Dispatchers.IO or Dispatchers.Main I quite do not understand what kind of dispatcher it creates. But yes I get the idea of it. Thank you so much guys, if you have any power more for explanation this last question I would be grateful.

Comment: A dispatcher is a coroutine concept, a piece of the context that intercepts coroutine continuations and basically controls where things run. The most common dispatcher implementations use a thread pool (or a single thread) to dispatch the work. `Dispatchers.IO/Default/Main` are just predefined dispatchers that use different thread pools. Room and other similar libraries create their own thread pools to deal with their I/O. You can think of their suspend functions as being wrapped in `withContext(customDispatcher)` where the custom dispatcher just wraps their custom thread pools

Comment: This means that it is pointless to do `withContext(Dispatchers.X) { roomCall() }` because that dispatcher will immediately be overridden again by the room implementation to switch to their own.

Comment: Ok, Joffrey thank you Coroutine Jedi. I am really interested in that topic, so in new year I;m buing the book by Marcin Moskała Kotlin Coroutines: Deep Dive. I hope it help me to understand it much better. 
I'm currently improving coroutines in applications and the idea about creating job was to after it just cancel it, because I;m doing it in repository class, not in fragment/viewmodel. Basically the question is does CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {} will be auto cancelled by itself after end of the coroutine or it will work as Global for the entire application which I do not want.

Comment: I could make a job as well in the repository class or I can change it to just normally calling scope with main. Thanks so much.